# uber/jaeger-client-node: backend wont receive data

Tags: node.js, uber-api, opentracing, jaeger

I'm currently looking into different openTracing Tracer-Implementations.
I want to use [uber/jaeger-client-node](https://github.com/uber/jaeger-client-node) but the backend won't receive my traces.

Here is what I did:
I started the all-in-one docker image:
`docker run -d -p5775:5775/udp -p16686:16686 jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest`

Next, i wrote a simple example application:
[Gist](https://gist.github.com/julianste/908612cdbac518eff5416fb8d89fafb6)

But when I go to Jaeger UI, nothing is shown about the example service. 
What did I do wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here. One is that your code sets the port for Jaeger client to 5775. This port expects a different data model than what Node.js client sends, you can remove the `agentHost` and `agentPort` parameters and rely on defaults.

The second issue is that you're running the Docker image without exposing the required UDP port. The correct command is shown in the [documentation](http://jaeger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/), as of today it should be this (one long line):

```
docker run -d -p5775:5775/udp -p6831:6831/udp -p6832:6832/udp \
    -p5778:5778 -p16686:16686 -p14268:14268 jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
```